# Difference Between Remote IP Addresses And Physical Addresses

Tags: ip-address

What is the difference between Remote IP address and Physical Address ?

Are these two things the same or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the address used at two different level.

IP is a software virtual name assigned to a machine.

Physical address (if you mean MAC with this) is a unique code that belong to a comunication interface.

Physical address is used at a lower level to physically route the message.

Reference to OSI model: [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)